# can't see object properties in Autodesk Forge Viewer for Revit linked files

Tags: autodesk-forge, revit-api

I'm publishing a Revit file with one linked file.
As per forge documentation, (https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/tutorials/translate-zip-to-stl/) I create a zip file and push it to forge cloud.
Everything is going well, I can correcly load the project with viewer, but if I look at objects from linked file, I cannot see their properties, or find them on search box.

It's like data from linked files is just for "background", I can click every single object, but I cannot interact with them just like ones in  main file.

Had anyone same issue and knows what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I'm checking with the Model Derivative service engineering team and will let you know as soon as I get their feedback. In the meantime, try looking at the sqlite database with your Revit model's metadata (https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/accessing-design-metadata-without-viewer) - perhaps the properties coming from the linked models are there, just hidden.

Comment: Hey Petr, thank you for your reply. I m sure that linked models objects properties are in the db, I m already able to extract them with Revit API, but I need to see them in forge viewer.

Comment: Thank you also for the link, this means it s also possible to extract data in a structured way directly from forge. Actually I separated data extraction from forge model translation and need a Revit installation for first step. As I read, I can do both for example uploading an rvt with a web application.

Answer (score 0):

Properties from *linked* models should be available and accessible just like the properties from the *main* model. If you don't see them, there might be another issue. In that case I'd suggest that you contact us via `forge (dot) help (at) autodesk (dot) com`, and if possible, include the sample models that can reproduce the issue.